# How to make kde scrollbars darker

Tags: kde, window-manager, scrollbar

I'm using ubuntu with awesomewm and kterminal (the kde terminal app).

Whenever I'm using the terminal (or any other app, but specifically the terminal), whenever I wanted to scroll, I find it very difficult to see the scroll bar so I can hold it with the mouse. Its color is so light that it is almost identical to the background.

Is there a way to make it black or even a little bit darker so I can see it better?

[image]

Comment: Don't you have any desktop environment like Gnome or Plasma? - This is a theming problem related to awesomewm window manager, but Gnome, Plasma or any DE is bound to affect theming.  If you don't have a DE like Gnome, edit your question and focus it on awesomewm, because as such it has little to do with kde or ubuntu. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=awesomewm+scrollbar+color - You could ask a awesomewm-specific question on unix.stackexchange.

Comment: Thank you very much.